# newly formated disk is read only

Tags: disk, format, gnome-disk-utility

I just reformatted a hard drive, with the ntfs file system, and its showing up as read only. How can I make it writeable?

here is dmesg:

```
~$ dmesg | tail
[49340.213245] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[49340.213251] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[49340.213709] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[49340.223618]  sdb: unknown partition table
[49340.269165] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[49590.985052] UDF-fs: warning (device sdb): udf_load_vrs: No anchor found
[49590.985056] UDF-fs: Rescanning with blocksize 2048
[49591.183252] UDF-fs: warning (device sdb): udf_load_vrs: No anchor found
[49591.183257] UDF-fs: Rescanning with blocksize 2048
[49591.222542] UDF-fs: INFO Mounting volume 'ESD-ISO', timestamp 2015/08/02 19:41 (1f10)
```

and

```
fdisk -l
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   ?     6579571  1924427647   958924038+  70  DiskSecure Multi-Boot
/dev/sdb2   ?  1953251627  3771827541   909287957+  43  Unknown
/dev/sdb3   ?   225735265   225735274           5   72  Unknown
/dev/sdb4      2642411520  2642463409       25945    0  Empty
```

I used the disk utility program, to do formatting.

Comment: DiskSecure Multi-boot, replaces the Master Boot Record on a hard disk with its own code. The necessary elements of the original partition table are stored on an unused part of the disk and presented to the authenticated operating system as required. Unauthorized boot programs (such as the Azusa, Stones, Brain viruses) will not be able to access the partition table as expected. You should create a new partition with gparted to make it accessible.